# Upgrading Azure Tiers

Tags: azure

Ok Ive been trying to find a definitive answer for this but it keeps getting me more confused trying to differentiate between people talking about VMs and Website plans, and different tier names being introduced, and the whole "Website Hosting Plan" where all your sites are now tied together in the plan.

Pretty much all I want to know is if I started an Azure account and made three free websites. Then I go to the Scale tab and upgrade it to Shared, it will say "all the websites in your plan will be affected" and change all three sites to Shared. Does this apply the ~$9.90 Shared price to each of the three sites (~$30) or does that ~$9.90 cover all the sites in the that shared hosting plan (I believe 100 is the max).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Shared mode, you pay for **each** Web Site.  In Standard mode, you pay for the VM that can host unlimited Web Sites (limit was 500 before).

So if you do the math, starting at 8 Web sites, it makes sense to go to Standard. It's even cheaper with the new Basic tier.

Comment: Ok thanks, thats what I figured it just seemed weird that they would go from pay for each site (free/shared) to pay for the whole vm (basic/standard) in the same Websites tab and not have the Vms in the Virtual Machine tab.